# Extract text in proper format (with spaces in between) from <td> tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract column headings from one of the tables from [ABBV 10-k](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1551152/000155115218000014/abbv-20171231x10k.htm) sec filing (`*Issuer Purchases of Equity Securities*' table on **page 25** - *below the graph*.)

inside `<td>` tag in the column heading `<tr>` tag, text is in separate `<div>` tags as in the example below

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>string1</div>
    <div>string2</div>
    <div>string3</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

when trying to extract all text fro a  tag, there is no space separation between texts (e.g. for the above html output will be `string1string3string3` expected`string1 string3 string3`).

Using below code to extract **column headings** from table

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1551152/000155115218000014/abbv-20171231x10k.htm'
htmlpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')[76]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
table_data = []
for tr in rows[2:3]:
    row_data=[]
    cells = tr.find_all(['td', 'th'], recursive=False)
    for cell in cells[1:4]:
        row_data.append(cell.text.encode('utf-8'))
    table_data.append([x.decode('utf-8').strip() for x in row_data])

print(table_data)
```

> **output:**`[['(a) TotalNumberof Shares(or Units)Purchased', '', '(b) AveragePricePaid per Share(or Unit)']]`
>
> **Expected output:**`[['(a) Total Number of Shares (or Units) Purchased', '', '(b) Average Price Paid per Share (or Unit)']]` *(each word separated bay a space)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `separator` parameter with `.get_text()`:

```
html = '''<tr>
  <td>
    <div>string1</div>
    <div>string2</div>
    <div>string3</div>
  </td>
</tr>'''

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

td = soup.find('td')
td.get_text(separator=' ')
```

Here's how it looks with your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1551152/000155115218000014/abbv-20171231x10k.htm'
htmlpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')[76]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
table_data = []
for tr in rows[2:3]:
    row_data=[]
    cells = tr.find_all(['td', 'th'], recursive=False)
    for cell in cells[1:4]:
        row_data.append(cell.get_text(separator=' ').encode('utf-8'))
    table_data.append([x.decode('utf-8').strip() for x in row_data])

print(table_data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(table_data)
[['(a) Total Number of Shares (or Units) Purchased', '', '(b) Average Price Paid per Share (or Unit)']]
```

Comment: @chitown88 can you please provide a link to the documentation for `get_text()`. searched a lot for the same but couldn't find.

Comment: `get_text(separator=u", strip=False, types=(<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>,  <class 'bs4.element.CData'>))`
_Get all child strings, concatenated using the given separator._ (This is all i could find)